# Fail to fire Callback function in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do something when an action in a child widget is being triggered.  So I try to work with Callback function but when the button in NewWindow() is pressed, the callback function fails to fire, it doesn't generate any error but just doesn't work. Can someone please teach me what's wrong in my code? Thanks a lot.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool CallbackFired = false;

class test_Callback extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _test_Callback createState() => _test_Callback();
}

class _test_Callback extends State<test_Callback> {
  void initState() {}

  void _test() {
    print('hit');
    setState(() {
      CallbackFired = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        NewWindow(voidCallback: () {
          _test();
        }),
        if (CallbackFired == true)
          Text('Callback Fired'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NewWindow extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback voidCallback;

  NewWindow({required this.voidCallback});

  @override
  _NewWindowState createState() => _NewWindowState();
}

class _NewWindowState extends State<NewWindow> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          widget.voidCallback;
        },
        child: Text('am Callback'));
  }
}
```

Comment: use `onPressed: widget.voidCallback,` or if you have to: `onPressed: () { widget.voidCallback();
},` - of course the first version is much better

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Modalbtn(),
  ));
}

class Modalbtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModalbtnState createState() => _ModalbtnState();
}

class _ModalbtnState extends State<Modalbtn> {
  String value = "0";
  // Pass this method to the child page.
  void _update(String newValue) {
    setState(() => value = newValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [StatefulModalbtn(update: _update)],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              iconSize: 20,
            ),
            Text(
              value,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class StatefulModalbtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> update;
  StatefulModalbtn({required this.update});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => update("100"), // Passing value to the parent widget.

      child: Text('Update (in child)'),
    );
  }
}
```